# How to get the elements with maximum difference in the single array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

Suppose, a= [3,7, 8,66,121,223,228] how to get the elements with maximum difference among them?
I have this solution to it but will appreciate better code than this.

```
let arr = []
a.sort((a,b)=>{
    return arr.push(a-b)
})
let index = arr.indexOf(Math.max(...arr))
a.sort((a,b)=> a-b).slice(index,index+2)
```

I expect the output to be [121,223]

Comment: why `121` and `223`?

Comment: Do you mean difference between 2 consecutive elements?

Comment: How the question is worded right now, just sounds like you want the `min` and `max` values in the array because those will be the elements with the greatest difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check each pair with the last found pair and get the one with the greatest delta.

```js
var array = [3, 7, 8, 66, 121, 223, 228],
    result = array.reduce((r, b, i, { [i - 1]: a }) => {
        if (i === 0) return;
        if (i === 1 || b - a > r[1] - r[0]) return [a, b];
        return r;
    }, undefined);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Awesome, Nina. Clear and Concise.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
 var a = [3,7, 8,66,121,223,228]
 var difference = 0;
 var pairIndex = 0;

 for(i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
  var currentItem = a[i];
  var nextItem = a[i+1];
  var currentDifference = Math.abs(currentItem - nextItem);

  if(currentDifference > difference) {
    difference = currentDifference;
    pairIndex = i;
  }
 }

var pair = [a[pairIndex], a[pairIndex + 1]];
return pair;
```

Comment: Nice, Shahzad. I think instead of for loop we can use array.map()  and can replace if statement with ternary operartor.

Comment: @VishavKirat07 Map basically just builds up a new structure and returns. We don't really need that overhead here.  We could not use ternary operator because there is no else part here. Also, we are executing multiple statements inside if. Wont be the best case scenario.

Answer (score 0):

```
a= [3,7, 8,66,121,223,228]
let MaxIntervalPosition = 0

for(let i=0;i<a.length-2;i++){
    if(Math.abs(a[i]-a[i+1]) > MaxIntervalPosition) {
        MaxIntervalPosition = i
    }
    return [a[i],a[i+1]]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below returns 3 elements

0 - The max difference found

1 - Element 1 of the pair.

2 - Element 2 of the pair.

using a `reduce` statement to iterate and find the pair is fairly simple. 
I have not tested this with randomized array.

```js
const array = [3,7, 8,66,121,223,228];

const maxDiff = (arr) => arr.reduce((a, v, i) =>
                              {
                                if(i === arr.length-1) return a;
                                const diff = Math.abs(v-arr[i+1]);
                                return (diff > a[0]) ? [diff, v, arr[i+1]] : a;
                              }, [0]);



console.log(maxDiff(array));

// use a simple destructure to seperate diff and elements
const  [diff, ...elements] = maxDiff(array);
console.log(elements);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this in a concise way with [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```js
let maxDiff = arr => arr.reduce((acc, c, i, arr) => { 
  if(i && c - arr[i-1] > arr[i-1] - arr[i-2])
    acc = [arr[i-1], c]
  return acc
}, [])

console.log(maxDiff([3,7,8,66,121,223,228]))      // <-- [121,223]
console.log(maxDiff([3,7,8,66,121,223,228,1000])) // <-- [228,1000]
```

The idea is to start from the **first** element `(i == 1)` and from there compare the difference between the last pair `arr[i-1] - arr[i-2]` and the current pair `(c - arr[i-1])`. If the difference is bigger overwrite the accumulator until you reach the end.

You can actually one line it via:

```js
let maxDiff = arr => arr.reduce((r,c,i,a) => 
  (r = i && c - a[i-1] > a[i-1] - (a[i-2] || 0) ? [a[i-1], c] : r, r), [])

console.log(maxDiff([3,7,8,66,121,223,228]))      // <-- [121,223]
console.log(maxDiff([3,7,8,66,121,223,228,1000])) // <-- [228,1000]
```

Comment: thumbs up, Akrion

Comment: Thanks. Glad I was able to help.