# Whats the best possible solution for getting a maximum difference between sucessive elements in a sorted array

Tags: javascript, node.js

If there is an array 
`let arr = [7,1,4,3,8]`, the result should be 3 which is maximum difference between 4 & 7.

Similarly, for `let arr2 = [5,5,5,7,4]`, output is 2 (between 5 & 7) and for `let arr3 = [6,3,2,5,9]` is 3 (between 6 & 9).

What's the best-optimized solution to find out the maximum difference.

My approach is to sort the array  and find out the difference between successive elements and then find the max value using `Math.max(...differenceValues)`

PS: I am not looking for a difference between max and min values in an array. The above question makes sense when you plot a graph on x-axis.

Comment: This likely belongs on the Computer Science Stack Exchange:  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165519/where-should-i-post-questions-about-algorithms-stack-overflow-or-software-engin

Comment: so sort and loop and hold the max value arr.sort().reduce()

Comment: You might want to add some of your own code to show what you have tried. Reason is, ATM the question looks like a subjective how-to / whats-the-best which will be voted down and may get flagged for close on the basis of not being a good format for SO.

Comment: How many values do you actually have? Is not having to sort a substantial performance improvement? I bet you can do better than `O(n log n)` (for average case at least), but at a high implementation complexity cost.

Comment: looks like that, with a sorted array: https://stackoverflow.com/q/56550131/1447675

Comment: @Bergi it was one of the technical questions asked in an interview. They might evaluate performance of the solution using varied lengths.

Comment: Is O(n*log(n)) actually an issue? This seems like premature optimization at its finest...

Comment: I just want to know my solution is already good to some extent or it can be optimized. I wrote a solution which includes looping twice (sort and then finding  the difference)

Comment: Well you should have shown your solution. ;) and if you used Max, you sort of used 3 loops.

Comment: I used Array.sort and then loop and find the differences between successive element and used Math.max(...arr). Currently I dont have solution. Trying to write it as we speak :-)

Comment: A good sorting algorithm should give you `O(n*log(n))` performance, using a linear scan afterwards is `O(n)`. If we take both together, that's still `O(n*log(n))` since we just leave the larger complexity. So, your sort -> search should have `O(n*log(n))` complexity which is *usually* pretty good for this sort of task. It might be improved but you start losing the maintainability and readability. For an interview, I'd personally stress those are more important than premature optimisation - if there is still a performance issue rooted at this code *then* we can have a look at it.

Comment: Thank you @VLAZ. That was a great explanation :-)

Answer (score 1):

Here is one using reduce:

```js
let arr = [7,1,4,3,8];

const max = arr.sort((a,b) => a-b)
               .reduce((result,currentValue,index) => {
                 if(result < arr[index + 1] - currentValue) {
                     return arr[index + 1] - currentValue
                 }
                 return result
               }, 0);

console.log(max);
```

Similar, but using `map` and `Math.max`

```js
let arr = [7,1,4,3,8];

const max2 = Math.max(...arr.sort((a,b) => a-b)
                .map((v, i) => (++i < arr.length) ? Math.abs(v - arr[i]) : 0));
                
console.log(max2);
```